# read Soap Response XML and insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml, soap

i'm trying to read response from XML SOAP file and then i need to insert it into the database

here's the XML Code

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <MobileAgentAPI:invokeResponse>
   <invokeReturn>
   <values xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="MobileAgentAPI:SoapMapValue[4]">
     <item>
      <name>balance</name>
      <singleValue>330123</singleValue>
     </item>
     <item>
      <name>returnCode</name>
      <singleValue>00</singleValue>
     </item>
     <item>
      <name>transactionStatus</name>
      <singleValue>00</singleValue>
     </item>
     <item>
      <name>errorCode</name>
      <singleValue>0</singleValue>
     </item>
     </values>
    </invokeReturn>
   </MobileAgentAPI:invokeResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

the question is.
how do i read the response and then insert the data into mysql?

thanks in advance

------UPDATE-------------------

I've tried this approach

```
$combi = '<XML Response>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($combi);
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

and it returns

```
balance
```

how do i loop through every node?
and print it like
balance       : 330123
returnCode    : 00
errorCode     : 0

and then insert it into mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can load the XML via DOMDocument in PHP and go through every node

more at: http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php

if you can specify your question i could help you more

update:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

instead of echo you could implement your sql code for each node

update 2:

```
$doc->loadXML($combi);
$data = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item'); 
foreach($data as $data){ 
 echo $data->item(0)->nodeValue . " : " . $data->item(1)->nodeValue, PHP_EOL; 

 }
```

Comment: i've tried    $doc->loadXML($combi);
   $data = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');
   foreach($data as $data){
     echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
   }
 and it returns returnCode00 transactionStatus00 dateTime1441955362000 errorCode0 DenominationS1 | lastBalance315123 |

Comment: isn't that what you want?

Comment: try this:     $doc->loadXML($combi);
    $data = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item'); 
    foreach($data as $data){ 
     echo $data->item(0)->nodeValue . " : " . $data->item(1)->nodeValue, PHP_EOL; 
     
     }